# CASE when is null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case

I am using a SQL Server database.

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  table1.name = 'something'
       AND CASE
             WHEN table1.date IS NULL THEN 1 = 1
             ELSE table1.date >= '2013-09-24'
           END;
```

gives me en error:

> [Error Code: 102, SQL State: S0001] Incorrect syntax near '='.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance

mismas

Comment: There are obvious problems, but without knowing what you are trying to do it's hard to suggest a fix.

Comment: I am trying to and part to where clause and use case...when...then...else...end. If date is null, then I want the and part in where clause to be always true, else if date is given, then I would like the and part of where clause to be date >= '2013-09-24'.

Comment: A `CASE` expression returns a value, e.g. `case when table1.date is NULL then 1 when table1.date >= '20130924' then 1 else 0 end = 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
select * 
from table1 
where table1.name='something' 
and (table1.date is null Or table1.date >= '2013-09-24');
```

Comment: Thank you all for comments, it helped me :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want.

```
select
    * 
from 
    table1 
where 
    table1.name = 'something' and (
        table1.date is null or 
        table1.date >= '2013-09-24'
    );
```

SQL Server doesn't really have a boolean type that you can use as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the coalesce keyword.

```
select
    *
from 
    table1
where 
    table1.name='something' and 
    coalesce(table1.date,'2013-09-24') >= '2013-09-24';
```

**[Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)** returns the first argument that is not null.